# Is local Notification feature available in iphone os below 4.0?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, localnotification

Is local Notification feature available in iphone OS below 4.0?In OS below 4.0 how can i send notification from the app even the app is not running.I don't want to use push notification(notification from any server side).Please guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, local notifications are only available in 4.0 and higher.

There are various third-party services such as [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com/) that greatly simplify the process of working with push notifications for developers. The API they provide is in some ways similar to local notifications in 4.0.

In my app I'm now using local notifications for users on 4.0, and UrbanAirship for people on older OS versions. As more people update to 4.0 I'll likely drop UrbanAirship, but currently it's about a 50/50 split.

Comment: Is there any way other than push notifications for iphone OS below 4.o?